# Flexibly assign chart bar color according to value - python-pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

Similar questions have been asked, but I still can't get it to work despite multiple tries. 
[Python PPTX Bar Chart negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223443/python-pptx-bar-chart-negative-values) ,
[Color Specific Bar Chart Differently in Python PPTX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42181540/color-specific-bar-chart-differently-in-python-pptx)

Here is a simple example:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import ChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.util import Cm
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor

_red = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)
_green = RGBColor(0, 128, 0)

# create presentation with 1 slide ------
prs = Presentation()
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[5])
x = ['one','two','three', 'four']
y = [-257.0, 1920.0, 2809.0, 500.0]
specs = {
    'height': Cm(7.82),
    'width': Cm(14.8),
    'left': Cm(2.53),
    'top': Cm(5.72)}

data = ChartData()
data.categories = x
label_values = tuple(y)
data.add_series('Series 1', label_values)
frame = slide.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.BAR_CLUSTERED,                 
specs['left'],specs['top'], specs['width'],specs['height'], data)
chart = frame.chart
series = chart.series[0]

for i in range(0,len(y)):
    point = series.points[i]
    fill = point.format.fill
    fill.solid()
    fill.fore_color.rgb = _red if y[i]<0 else _green
series.invert_if_negative = False

prs.save('chart-01.pptx')
```

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx40V.png)

[What I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiOUV.png)

I have tried many different configurations. Python-pptx is working, because by setting the boolean to true or false in my code with `series.invert_if_negative` the checkbox acts accordingly when I open powerpoint presentation as shown in the second image. It only displays correctly in powerpoint if I manually toggle it a couple times after the presentation has already been generated. I tried changing the location of the statement, setting it to true or false and even having it alternate multiple times before settling on false.

Interestingly this only happens with negative bar chart i.e. with positive values I can change the color as I please. Even if all the values are negative. I can't set them all to a certain color. The only time they have color and don't display as white boxes is when I don't try to change their color at all and they default to the presentation theme colors.

I suspect this is a powerpoint issue rather than pptx-python problem, but any help in resolving this will be much appreciated!

Powerpoint version: 15.36 on Mac
Python-pptx version: 0.6.7

Thanks for the amazing library Scanny and your responses to all the other questions. It has been loads of help.

**=======UPDATE=======**

There is a workaround to this problem which is to use the patterned fill and set both back_color and fore_color to the same color to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a discrepancy between the default XML produced by `python-pptx` and that produced (and then later interpreted) by PowerPoint.

You should start by checking your version to make sure you're on the latest. There were a couple cases a while back where PowerPoint wasn't respecting the defaults stated in the spec, like perhaps `c:invertIfNegative` defaults to True. We added some code to fix those up.

Here are a couple tweaks to your code:

```
chart = slide.shapes.add_chart(
    XL_CHART_TYPE.BAR_CLUSTERED, specs['left'], specs['top'], 
    specs['width'], specs['height'], data
).chart
series = chart.series[0]
series.invert_if_negative = False

for idx, point in enumerate(series.points):
    fill = point.format.fill
    fill.solid()
    fill.fore_color.rgb = _red if y[idx]<0 else _green

print(series._element.xml)

prs.save('chart-01.pptx')
```

I don't think this fixes anything, but perhaps makes intent a little clearer and mostly prints out the XML for the series. You can move that line around before and after setting the invert option for example.

What you're looking for in that XML is an element like `<c:invertIfNegative val=0>`. If it's not present or has some other value, that would explain some things.

The "white" color on negative values is more precisely "no color", which now that I think of it could be because there is no *background* color set. It's reasonable to assume PowerPoint swaps foreground and background when "inverting". So one thing to try is setting the background color for negative items rather than foreground and see if that does anything interesting.

If you're unable to work this out, I recommend you open an issue on the GitHub issues list for `python-pptx` where we can dig into it a little better with the conversational mode there rather than with the Q&A format here.

Comment: The element does indeed adapt to the boolean I assign it as well as through the ppt UI. The problem is powerpoint doesn't seem to register it. If I set false I need to check and then the uncheck box for it to display correctly. If I set it to True then I simply need to uncheck it and it works. 
I thought background colors weren't 'settable'? Only the fore_color fill attribute allowed to set a color.
As a temporary solution I have used pattern and set both the fore and background color to the desired color.
I will open a github issue once I get the chance!

Comment: The next step would be to compare the XML generated by `python-pptx` and that generated by PowerPoint once you changed it back and forth enough to get it working. You can use the same `series._element.xml` bit, just accessing the existing chart rather than adding it as you did the first time. The cause is likely to be one of the things that are different between those two XML trees.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't got the pptx module installed so I couldn't test my answer. But I can see your if-statement is formatted incorrect.

Try this:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import ChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.util import Cm
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor

_red = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)
_green = RGBColor(0, 128, 0)

# create presentation with 1 slide ------
prs = Presentation()
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[5])
x = ['one','two','three', 'four']
y = [-257.0, 1920.0, 2809.0, 500.0]
specs = {
    'height': Cm(7.82),
    'width': Cm(14.8),
    'left': Cm(2.53),
    'top': Cm(5.72)}

data = ChartData()
data.categories = x
label_values = tuple(y)
data.add_series('Series 1', label_values)
frame = slide.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.BAR_CLUSTERED,                 
specs['left'],specs['top'], specs['width'],specs['height'], data)
chart = frame.chart
series = chart.series[0]

for i in range(0,len(y)):
    point = series.points[i]
    fill = point.format.fill
    fill.solid()
    if y[i]<0:
        fill.fore_color.rgb = _red  
    else:
        fill.fore_color.rgb = _green
series.invert_if_negative = False
```

Comment: Ternary conditional operators were added to python as of version 2.5, so the if else expression was in a valid format!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator