# Changing series fill color in python-pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

I just started using python-pptx, but have somewhat extensive experience working with Powerpoint between win32com, Visual Basic, Interop, etc., and I am seeing something funny when creating a chart with a single series.

**Problem:** a chart with a single series, by default, appears to be varying color fill *per point/category*. This is in contrast to what I'd expect: all points within a series should have the same color. (e.g., with win32com, these charts would have a single, consistent color across all points, buuuut there's some very finnicky stuff with win32com that requires basically rebuilding the ChartData and overwriting the default, plus the whole `Application` instance is doing its thing behind the scenes, which we don't have in OpenXML or pptx, etc, so that might be a factor in this apparent discrepancy)

[image]

**Question:** Is this the normal/expected behavior for a chart with a single series? Or am I overlooking something obvious?

I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42181540/color-specific-bar-chart-differently-in-python-pptx) and I was able to adapt your comments there to format the series consistently (below), but mainly I am wondering if this is necessary, or if I'm doing something wrong:

```
def FormatChart(chart):
    plot = chart.plots[0]
    plot.has_data_labels = True
    dl = plot.data_labels
    dl.position = XL_LABEL_POSITION.OUTSIDE_END

    value_axis = chart.value_axis
    value_axis.has_major_gridlines = False

    s = plot.series[0]
    s.format.fill.solid()
    s.format.fill.fore_color.theme_color = MSO_THEME_COLOR_INDEX.ACCENT_1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. The easy way to change it is by setting the `_BasePlot.vary_by_categories` property to `False`:

```
plot = chart.plots[0]
plot.vary_by_categories = False
```